# How do i organize my code using Git? Should i fork or branch?

Tags: git, branch, fork

I have a code base for a microcontroller that i forked. Unfortunately it's not yet a library of tools that could be compiled in other external project - when developing your specific microcontroller application, you might need to hack something in "core" modules. As long as it is on github, it is possible to keep it sane and push fixes and features to parent repo, etc, but i'm concerned about my specific applicaitons - where do i keep code for them?

As i understand, branch is considered a short-lived artefact in git? Should I fork my repo for each specific application?

The code in question is at https://github.com/Miceuz/LPC1343CodeBase i have main codebase in master and two branches - a temperature controller firmware and a LED board firmware.

Answer (score 1):

For separate projects I would go with forking and for development of a specific project make a branch. Imagine a project is a tree; you would have branches for each part of the project which can be merged to make a "big" branch which is still part of that tree then you can copy and "plant" the tree for a new project.

Its very late over here alright! :P